# if condition is false but output is true . what is the exact expression of greater than to bands value ('mjune@1'> 99.6:)

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, python-2.7, raster-calculator

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import os 
from osgeo import gdal
from array import *
import ctypes

entries = []
fileName = "E:/WRA/pet/mothmean81j82m.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName,baseName)

boh1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh1.ref = 'boh@1'
boh1.raster = rlayer
boh1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( boh1 )

if 'mjune@1' > 99.6:
    print "not calculate"
else:
    juneop = '( 16*mjune@1)'

print juneop

calc = QgsRasterCalculator(juneop, 'E:/WRA/pet/juneop11.tif', 'GTiff', rlayer.extent(), rlayer.width(), rlayer.height(), entries )
calc.processCalculation()
```

The if condition is not properly working exactly if condition is false but output is true .
what is the exact expression of greater than to  bands value ('mjune@1'> 99.6:).

Answer (score 2):

you cannot test a band (lots of value) against a single value as you do in Python. In fact your script is comparing a string ('mjune@1') with a number (99.6), which is not what you want (and is always true) .

If you want a conditional expression for each pixel value, it has to be inside your expression. For instance :

```
juneop = '(mjune@1>99.6)*16*mjune@1'
```

will test if mjune@1 is greater than 99.6 inside the raster calculator, for each pixel (this return "0" if false and "16*mjune@1" if true)

By the way, you entry is boh, then you use mjune. Maybe you did not provide all the code, but this need to be checked.